# Android Null Pointer Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, rss-reader, imagedownload

I've been using this site for ages, but this is the first time I've actually been unable to find an answer to my question. I'm following along with an online tutorial in order to add image thumbnails to my app from an RSS feed. I keep experiencing a NULL Pointer Error from my instantiation of convertView, but it is instantiated exactly how the tutorials have it so I don't understand why that is.

```
public class PostItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PostData> {
    private Activity myContext;
    private ArrayList<PostData> datas;
    private String[] imageURLArray;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView postTitleView;
        TextView postDateView;
        ImageView postThumbView;
        String postThumbViewURL;
        Bitmap bitmap;

    }

    public PostItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                           ArrayList<PostData> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        myContext = (Activity) context;
        datas = objects;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.postitem, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.postThumbView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postThumb);
            viewHolder.postTitleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postTitleLabel);
            viewHolder.postDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postDateLabel);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        PostData post = datas.get(position);
        if (post.postThumbUrl != null) {
            viewHolder.postThumbViewURL = post.postThumbUrl;
            new DownloadImageTask().execute(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder.postThumbView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_event);
        }

        viewHolder.postTitleView.setText(post.postTitle);
        viewHolder.postDateView.setText(post.postDate);
        new DownloadImageTask().execute(viewHolder);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
04-24 13:32:12.748    7335-7335/com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw, PID: 7335
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup)' on a null object reference
            at com.chuckfranklin.chuckfranklinlaw.PostItemAdapter.getView(PostItemAdapter.java:56)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2825)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1884)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:713)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:779)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1679)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2629)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2321)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2034)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6641)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: inflater is never initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `inflater`. Since you've got `Context` in constructor, you can do it at the following way:

```
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Of course, it should be added to constructor, not to `getView`.

Answer (score 0):

As in log:

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate

Clearly saying calling `inflate` method  using non initialized object of `LayoutInflater`. Initilize it as:

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
               myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't access a member without initializing it.

```
public PostItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<PostData> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    myContext = (Activity) context;
    inflater = Layourinflater.from(context);
    datas = objects;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inflater is never initialized, so you get this error.

Use this

```
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a line of code in your getView() before initializing convertview as in:

```
if (convertView == null) {
 // This a new view we inflate the new layout              
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
 context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.postitem, null);
}
```